# Removing duplicate frames with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp4 file, samp1.mp4,  that has duplicate frames and I've tried to use mpdecimate to remove them. The FFmpeg command line I used is

```
ffmpeg -i samp1.mp4 -vf mpdecimate out3.mp4 > out3.txt 2>&1
```

But the output file, out3.mp4, still has the duplicate frames.

The command generates the text:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'samp1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-12-26T20:38:35.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:04.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4495 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, 4476 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-26T20:38:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding

Output #0, mp4, to 'out3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-26T20:38:35.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.42.104 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=   2.9kbits/s dup=35 drop=0 speed=0.262x    
frame=   87 fps= 75 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.13 bitrate=1848.9kbits/s dup=56 drop=0 speed=0.978x    
frame=  117 fps= 65 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.13 bitrate= 982.2kbits/s dup=74 drop=0 speed=1.19x    
frame=  142 fps= 62 q=29.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate= 706.3kbits/s dup=88 drop=0 speed=1.29x    
frame=  142 fps= 47 q=-1.0 Lsize=     720kB time=00:00:04.63 bitrate=1271.0kbits/s dup=88 drop=0 speed=1.52x
```

=================== 
These last five lines of output are interesting. The first line

```
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=29.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=   2.9kbits/s dup=35 drop=0 speed=0.262x
```

seems to say that frame 57 was a duplicate, the total number of duplicates found now = 35, and the total frames dropped is 0.

1) Is that correct, 2) why weren't any frames dropped on any of the lines, and 3) why does the output file still contain duplicates?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: This SO site is the only one I could find with an ffmpeg tag. If you could recommend a better site for ffmpeg questions I'd be glad to use it.

Comment: consider posting on https://video.stackexchange.com ... e.g. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20958/ffmpeg-dropping-duplicate-frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MP4, by default, is a constant frame-rate muxer in ffmpeg, so timestamp gaps created by mpdecimate will be plugged back in, by duplicate frames.

The solution is to set variable frame-rate mode.

```
ffmpeg -i samp1.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -vsync vfr out3.mp4 > out3.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Ok,. great to know! Could you possibly point me to the ffmpeg documentation that spells that out?  Also the documentation that explains the dup=35 and drop=0 terms in my example?  Thank you very much!